# Convolution of distribution and test function: continuity at the distribution variable

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, convolution

In the book *Functional Analysis* of Rudin, the following theorem is proved: given a distribution $u$ and a sequence of test functions $\phi_n$ which converges to $\phi$, we have that  $u *\phi_n $ converges to $u * \phi$ in the sense of $C^\infty$. We call $f_n$ converges to $f$ in the sense of $C^\infty$, if every partial derivative of $f_n$ uniformly converges to the correspondent partial derivative of $f$ on every compact set.

**My question is:** if the test function $\phi$ is fixed, and we are given a convergent sequence of distributions $u_n$ with limit $u$, do we  have again the convergence of $u_n * \phi$ in $C^\infty$?

I think this is a very natural question. I have proved the pointwise convergence of $u_n * \phi$, and it seems $u_n * \phi$ converges in the sense of distribution too. I believe the convergence in $C^\infty$ is false, but I can't  construct a counterexample. I would be very grateful if anyone could help.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion. Show that for a dense set of test functions $\psi$ (chosen to be independent of $n$),

$< u_n * \phi, \psi>= <u_n, \phi*\psi>$

Comment: Thanks. I think it shows $u_n * \phi$ converges in the sense of distribution, but I still don't know whether $u_n * \phi$ converges in the sense of $C^\infty$.

Comment: Consider the sum of a  $n$of delta functions at first $n$ integers. Its convolution with $\phi$ translates $\phi$ $n$ times and adds all such copies.. The limit distribution creates a periodic function that is smooth but  not of compact support.